# Running powershell via Start-Proces with elevated credentials hangs for several minutes on Win7 64bit when on network

Tags: powershell, 64-bit

I have a number of scripts that require sections of them to run with elevated privileges.

If I do the following:

```
pw= convertto-securestring "PASSWORD" -asplaintext –force
 $pp = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "DOMAIN\user",$pw
 $script = "c:\pathtoscript.ps1"
 Start-Process powershell -Credential $pp -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process $script -verb runas}'
```

It works fine when there is no network cable connected. However, when I try with the network connected it hangs for 2-3 minutes, although it does finally run the script.

To make it even weirder, it works fine opening any process other than Powershell, and it works fine opening powershell if there are no arguments specified.

Comment: What is this $Model=$RamCal.Model? Where is $ramcal?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a PowerShell issue. It is to do with home directory access.

Can you try this registry change?

Add a REG_DWORD value named StartRunNoHOMEPATH in the following registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

Comment: Is that under the "elevated" user or the standard user?

Comment: change it for standard use who is elevating

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately.